# SAR Doppler centroid estimation

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, radar

I read book Comming Wong Digital Processing of Synthetic apperture, where they describe in detail various metods for estimation doppler centroid. Fractional part and resolve ambiguous.

But in tne practice i get unclear situation.

When I use the phase method to get the fractional part, fiding average cross correlation coefficient (ACCC) i get some time angel which is on the edge of the range -pi/2,pi/2.

This is how I calculate

1. I calculate summ of product:

   C(n) = sum(s"(n)*s(n+dn))
   where  dn azimuth sampling interval of 1/PRF.

2 Next I calculate the angle of the ACCC:

A_ACCC = angle(C);

The result can be seen in the image below

[image]

I thought I needed to evaluate Doppler ambiguity, but it is calculated based on angle of the ACCC (when use MLCC), which have errors.

I understand that I have a center Doppler frequency close to the -pi/2 and even a little further.

But I did not find a solution to this problem in the literature. Any method that I would use, phase based or amplitude, would give incorrect results.

In "А Combined SAR Doppler Centroid Estimation Scheme  Based upon  Signal Phasei" the same author wrote:

**Since one or both of the АССС angles фL, mау have been wrapped around,  а  simple  discontinuity  detector  is  used  to set fc
to within  the  interval  ±Fa/2.**

But how do you determine regarding what to align? -Fa/2 or +Fa/2?
As i understand it, in order to do this, i must know the sign of the Doppler center frequency.